# Undefined variable when trying to pass username and password through Ansible Git Module

Tags: ansible

I have a follow up question to the thread in here:
[How do I pass username and password while using Ansible Git module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841914/how-do-i-pass-username-and-password-while-using-ansible-git-module)

I am trying to achieve a similar task where I am passing a username and password to GitHub through Ansible. Here is what I am using for my playbook:

```
- name: ANSIBLE - Shop Installation
  hosts: host_list
  vars_prompt: 
    - name: "githubuser" 
      prompt: "Enter your github username" 
      private: no 
    - name: "githubpassword" 
      prompt: "Enter your github password" 
      private: yes

- hosts: host_list
  tasks:
  - name: Get the latest version through Git
    git:
    repo: 'https://{{ githubuser }}:{{ githubpassword }}@github.com/foo/bar.git'
    dest: /tmp
```

After running through this, I get the following error message:

fatal: []: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'githubuser' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'playbook.yml'

Any ideas where I may have gone wrong here?

I am running Ansible 2.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the structure of your playbook is wrong. Try this:

```
---
- hosts: host_list
  vars_prompt: 
    - name: "githubuser" 
      prompt: "Enter your github username" 
      private: no 
    - name: "githubpassword" 
      prompt: "Enter your github password" 
      private: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Get the latest version through Git
    git:
      repo: 'https://{{ githubuser }}:{{ githubpassword }}@github.com/foo/bar.git'
      dest: /tmp
```

Comment: Yup, you're right; my structure was incorrect. Your suggestion fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Scope](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables) of *vars_prompt* is a playbook.

Variable *githubuser* is defined in the first play. Second play knows nothing about it.

> Would I have to pass the variable value from the first play to the second? What's the correct way of doing that in this context?

An option would be to configure [fact_caching](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/plugins/cache.html#enabling-cache-plugins). For example with Redis

```
[defaults]
fact_caching=redis
```

In the first play store the variables with [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html#set-fact-set-host-facts-from-a-task) *cacheable: yes*

In the second play [fetch data from Redis](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/redis.html#redis-fetch-data-from-redis)

Comment: Would I have to pass the variable value from the first play to the second? What's the correct way of doing that in this context?